# triangle definition vs quadrilateral definition

Tags: geometry

Consider a reflex quadrilateral ie one that has one internal angle > 180 degrees.  Modify the quadrilateral so that the angle decreases.  When the angle is less than 180 the shape is still a quadrilateral.  When the angle is exactly 180 the shape is a triangle but is it still a quadrilateral,  If not what definition of a quadrilateral has it violated?  My wondering about this stems from a lecturer casually mentioning that "hour glass" quadrilateral where the corners are joined in the wrong order still counted and whether that inclusion extended to ones with an internal angle of 180.

Comment: If it has four vertices, it's a quadrilateral.

Comment: "the shape is a triangle but is it still a quadrilateral ... ." I would say the shape is then _concurrent_ with a triangle. It's only a triangle if you decide to delete a vertex.